# Shiny: update selectinput on change of inFile

Tags: shiny, updates

I want to provide inputselect "choices" in dependency of uploaded files (fileInput). In the example below I want `as.list(mydata[1, 1:5])` as values for inputselect choices. Later on the subsetting values will be dynamic and is not showed here.

[image]

I tried several approaches suggested in the forum (reactive, observe, reactiveValue and their combination) without much success.

My script runs partially, however I need a page refresh to the get the "choices" uploaded and reload the file again.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$contents <- renderDataTable({

    inFile <<- input$SoftRecom
    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
    filedatapath <<- reactive({inFile$datapath})
    mydata <<- read.csv(filedatapath(), header = TRUE, sep = ',')
    mydata
})


mychoices <<- reactive({
    mydata
    print(mydata)
    })

output$vg <- renderUI({
    selectInput("vg", label =  p("goal", style = "color:#FFA500"), 
       mychoices()[1,1:5], selected = 1)
})   

output$vp <- renderUI({
    selectInput("procedure", label =  p("procedure", style = "color:#FFA500"), 
                choices = c("proecudures"), selected = 1)

})

output$vm <- renderUI({
    selectInput("procedure", label =  p("procedure", style = "color:#FFA500"), 
                choices = c("ChIP-seq"), selected = 1)

})
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
titlePanel("simple software recommendation sytem"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('SoftRecom', 'choose dataset'),

        uiOutput("vg"), # variable goal 
        uiOutput("vp"), # variable procedure
        uiOutput("vm")  # variable method


    ),
    mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput('contents')
    )
)
))
```

I have seen many examples and answers in the forum, that are very close (or even match) my question. Sorry for being so obtuse. If someone could point me to the problem, I would be very thankful.

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution by myself. Don't get confused by the different server code in my question and the answer.  Just look at the relationship between

- uiOutput('pipelinestep') and
- output$pconst <<- renderUI({selectizeInput(
      'pconst', 'construct software workflow', choices = as.character(mysoft[mysoft$goal==mypipefilter, 3]),
      multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 1))}

UI.R

I had to insert: uiOutput("pipelinestep") see line 8

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
titlePanel( h2("simple software recommendation system", style = "color:#FFA500")),
    sidebarLayout(position = "left",
        sidebarPanel(width =3,
             # chose standard pipeline
             selectInput("selectpipe", "select standard pipeline:", choices = pipechoices),
             # software details
             *uiOutput("pipelinestep")*, # software per pipeline step,
             # construct software workflow based on selected pipeline step 
             uiOutput("pconst")
        ))))
```

server.R

see from line 5 to 7. "Choices" gets new values assigned as soon a change is detected. Please see documentation here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

```
pipelinestepsoftInput <<- reactive({
    mypipefilter <- input$pipelinestep
    softperpipe <<- mysoft[mysoft$goal==mypipefilter ,c(1,3,5:7), drop = FALSE]
    ## provides software choices related to the pipeline step
    output$pconst <<- renderUI({selectizeInput(
        'pconst', 'construct software workflow', choices = as.character(mysoft[mysoft$goal==mypipefilter, 3]),
        multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 1))})
    ## input for outputDataTable
    softperpipe 
    })
```